# casting with interface inheritance

Tags: c#, interface

I'm trying to use interface instead of concrete implementation and I'm facing a design issue with the code below when trying to call the `Get()` method from interfaceA.

- `classA` implements `interfaceA`
- `interfaceB` inherits from `interfaceA`
- `classB` inherits from `classA` and implements `interfaceB`

I know how to cast, as etc... but is this acceptable? Is it a best practice?
Just wondering if there are other ways to handle such scenarios.
Thx

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        interfaceA a = new classA();
        interfaceB b = a.Get(); // compilation error
        interfaceB bb = a.Get() as interfaceB; // Ok
    }
}

interface interfaceA
{
    interfaceA Get();
}

class classA : interfaceA
{
    interfaceA ia;

    public classA()
    {
        ia = new classA();
    }

    public interfaceA Get()
    {
        return ia;
    }
}

interface interfaceB : interfaceA
{

}

class classB : classA, interfaceB
{

}
```

Comment: classA's ctor is recursive which also needs fixing, its unclear what that logic is intended to do ...

Comment: It's definitely not the best practice. You are trying to do risky downcasting which in your case cannot succeed as constructed instance of `classA` doesn't implement `interfaceB`.

Comment: I think you'd be better off modelling something a bit more concrete e.g. shapes or cat vs dog vs IAnimal, then things like your classA constructor would look more obviously strange...e,g, if classA was Dog, youd be trying to construct a dog inside a dog inside a dog...forever.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is, that a.Get() returns an interfaceA and while interfaceB is assignable from interfaceA, interfaceA is NOT assignable from interfaceB. So although, classB inherits from classA, it still needs to properly implement interfaceB, which will have some different methods/properties than interfaceA. You need to  use a more abstract class to assign a more specific one. e.g. `interfaceA a = new classB();` since classB is guaranteed to have all properies in methods of interfaceA. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the real use case, I don't call the constructor from `classA`.
Instead, I use a method that takes an object of type `interfaceA` not yet created which is created with the correct type (`classB`).
The real issue when I'm trying to call the method from `classA`. It returns an `interfaceA` in order to set an object of `interfaceB`.

```
interfaceB bb = a.Get();
```

The code looks like:

```
Insert(root, i);

private void Insert(interfaceB<T> node, T newItem)
{
    interfaceB<T> current = node;
    if (root == null)
    {
        interfaceB<T> newNode = new classB<T>(newItem);
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    // some code
    current = current.GetLeft(); // error since GetLeft() return a interfaceA<T>
    // some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error here:

```
interfaceB b = a.Get(); // compilation error
               ^^ return value is cast as interfaceA.
```

...is because the method returns an object cast as `interfaceA` and tries to cast it as `interfaceB`. Because of inheritance, anything that implements `interfaceB` also implements `interfaceA`. But the opposite isn't true.

For example, `ClassA` implements `interfaceA`, but it doesn't implement `interfaceB`. So you can't do this:

```
interfaceB b = new ClassA();
```

You would get the same compiler error for the same reason.

This is true even if your method looked like this:

```
public interfaceA Get()
{
    return new ClassB();
}
```

That method would compile, because `ClassB` does implement `interfaceA`.

But this still would not compile:

```
interfaceB b = a.Get(); // compilation error
```

...because the result of the function is *cast* as `interfaceA`. In other words, when you call this method, the only thing the caller knows is that it gets an `interfaceA`. It doesn't know what the concrete class is. It may or may not be something that implements `interfaceB`.

The compiler error forces you to figure all of that up front instead of running the program and then getting an error. That's awesome. We want that. It's much harder to figure out the problem when the program is running. It's so much better if the compiler shows us the problem.

In your question you mentioned casting. While there are occasions for casting, it's often used as a way to circumvent the compiler, getting our code to compile so that we can run it.

If we do that, this line *will* compile:

```
interfaceB b = (interfaceB)a.Get();
               ^^ whatever this method returns, cast it as interfaceB.

// just like this one compiles
interfaceB bb = a.Get() as interfaceB; // Ok
```

That's great, but when we run it we'll get an exception *if* the object returned doesn't actually implement `interfaceB`. And that will be an exception we could have avoided if we let the compiler do its job and warn us.

**The solution**
There isn't just one. Or, we might say, there might be one but it's specific to the code you're writing right now, not something general. But here are some suggestions:

First, it's good to avoid introducing inheritance unless we really need it. Inheritance is not bad, but we often have a tendency to use it unnecessarily.

Second, when we inherit or implement interfaces, we should usually write code so that the only type we care about is the type that is declared. So, for example, if we call this method:

```
ISomeInterface GiveMeAnObject() 
{
    return new ThingThatImplementsTheInterface(); 
}
```

...the only thing we care about when we get that object is that it implements `ISomeInterface`. We don't want to know anything at all about the concrete class, other classes that implement the interface, or other interfaces that inherit from `ISomeInterface`. Our code shouldn't care about that. The primary goal is to avoid having to know or care about those details. If we do know or care about those details and we find ourselves saying, "I know that my `ISomeInterface` is *really* an instance of this class or that class" and we cast it, then something has gone wrong.

One possible exception to that is *downcasting*. In certain cases this might make sense:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {}
public interface ISomeInheritedInterface : ISomeInterface {}

public ISomeInheritedInterface GetSomething()
{
    return new ClassThatImplementsInheritedInterface();
}

ISomeInterface foo = GetSomething();
```

In this case we're getting an object and casting it as one of its base types. That's okay because it doesn't involve making any assumptions. We know that *every* `ISomeInheritedInterface` is *always* an `ISomeInterface`, so that's okay. That's also while the compiler allows it.

Other than that, most of our normal solutions to normal problems should not involve casting. Whenever possible - which is almost all the time - we shouldn't need to do that. If we want to keep track of all of the types ourselves instead of letting the compiler do it, we could just declare every variable and every function as `object` and then cast everything. That would be a nightmare and make programming much harder. (Or we could program in VB.NET with `Option Strict` turned off, which is pretty much the same thing.)